# TypeError: undefined is not a function in Angular Resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-resource

When trying to poll a custom method `copies` on an AngularJS Resource I get the following error at `angular.js:10033`: (The method `copy` works just fine.)

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.8/angular-resource.min.js:9:347
at Array.forEach (native)
at q (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.8/angular.min.js:7:280)
at q.then.p.$resolved (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.8/angular-resource.min.js:9:329)
at J (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.8/angular.min.js:101:5)
at J (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.8/angular.min.js:101:5)
at https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.8/angular.min.js:102:173
at g.$eval (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.8/angular.min.js:113:138)
at g.$digest (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.8/angular.min.js:110:215)
at g.$apply (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.8/angular.min.js:113:468)
```

Angular.js 10016 - 10035:

```
function consoleLog(type) {
  var console = $window.console || {},
      logFn = console[type] || console.log || noop,
      hasApply = false;

  // Note: reading logFn.apply throws an error in IE11 in IE8 document mode.
  // The reason behind this is that console.log has type "object" in IE8...
  try {
    hasApply = !!logFn.apply;
  } catch (e) {}

  if (hasApply) {
    return function() {
      var args = [];
      forEach(arguments, function(arg) {
        args.push(formatError(arg));
      });
      return logFn.apply(console, args); // This is line 10033 where the error gets thrown.
    };
  }
```

Simplified resource:

```
angular.module('vgm.content-pages')
.factory('ContentPage', function($resource, $http) {

  return $resource('/api/content-page/:id', { id:'@page.id' }, {
    copy: {
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/api/content-page/copy/:id'
    },
    copies: {
      method: 'GET',
      isArray: true,
      url: '/api/content-page/copies/:id'
    }
  });

});
```

Simplified directive where I'm getting the error:

```
angular.module('vgm.genericForms')
.directive('vgmFormCopyPicker', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '/static/common/generic-forms/widgets/view-copy-picker.html',
    scope: {
      resource: '=',
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element) {

      $scope.pages = [];

      $scope.loadCopies = function() {

        $scope.resource.$copies()
          .then(function(response) {
            $scope.pages = response.data;
          });

      };

    }
  };

});
```

As soon as I run the `loadCopies` method, executing the line `$scope.resource.$copies()` throws the error above.

In the Chrome Inspector I see the call to my API is actually being done. But resolving the promise seems to throw some error...

How can I solve this error?

EDIT:

```
$scope.resource = ContentPage.get({id: $stateParams.id}).$promise
$scope.resource.$save() // Works
$scope.resource.$update() // Works
$scope.resource.$copy() // Works
$scope.resource.$copies() // Does not work!
```

Angular Resource is trying to overwrite my initial resource with an array of items. But the instance of Resource does not have a method `push` of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer:

A resource is supposed to represent the matched data object for the rest of its lifespan. If you want to fetch new data you should do so with a new object.

```
$scope.copies = ContentPage.copies()
```

Comment: Thanks Guido. I had this same problem. I think the docs are a bit confusing. If I'm understanding it correctly, you can't call an instance method which has isArray:true on a /single/ resource instance because the single instance is not an array.

Comment: That's correct.

And it makes sense if you think about it: first the property represents a list of items, and suddenly it represents a single item, that's not consistent.

Answer (score 6):

The answer from Guido is correct but I didn't get it at the first time.

If you add a custom method to your Angular `$resource` and using `isArray: true` and expecting to get an Array of something from your WebService you probably want to store the response in an Array.

Therefore you shouldn't use the instance method like this:

```
var ap = new Ansprechpartner();
$scope.nameDuplicates = ap.$searchByName(...);
```

But use the resource directly:

```
$scope.nameDuplicates = Ansprechpartner.searchByName(...)
```

Using following Angular resource:

```
mod.factory('Ansprechpartner', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/Ansprechpartner/:id', 
            { id: '@ID' },
            {
                "update": { method: "PUT" },
                "searchByName": { method: "GET", url: "/api/Ansprechpartner/searchByName/:name", isArray: true }
            }
        );
    }
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using `Mean.js` and this plagued for a few hours. There is a built in `$update` but it was not working when I tried to apply it to an object returned by a `$resource`. In order to make it work I had to change how I was calling the resource to update it.

For example, with a `Student` module, I was returning it with a `$resource` into `$scope.student`. When I tried to update `student.$update` was returning this error. By modifying the call to be `Students.update()` it fixed the problem.

```js
 $scope.update = function() {
   var student = $scope.student;
   var result = Students.update(student);

   if(result){
      $scope.message = 'Success';
   } else {
      $scope.error = 
        'Sorry, something went wrong.';
   }
 };
```