# Angular - Directive with dynamic template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, caching, angularjs-directive

I created a directive with dynamic template and it is working well.
The problem is that I am getting an error:

> At Chrome = TypeError: undefined is not a function at forEach.attr
>   At Firefox = Error: element.setAttribute is not a function

Here is the code:

```
return {
    restrict:'E',
    replace:true,
    scope:{
        content:'@'
    },
    controller:function($scope){
        $scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
            if($scope.content.match(/<img/i) && !$scope.content.match(/icon-subs/i)) {
                return 'app/templates/_image.html';
            } else if ($scope.content.match(/<a/i)) {
                return 'app/templates/_link.html';
            } else if ($scope.content.match(/<iframe/i)) {
                return 'app/templates/_video.html';
            } else {
                return 'app/templates/_minutes.html';
            }
        }
    },
    template: '<div ng-include="getTemplateUrl()"></div>'
};
```

The directive tag:

```
<div ng-repeat="lance in contentsArray">
    <icone-timeline data-content="{{lance.content}}"></icone-timeline>
    <div ng-bind-html="lance.content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: template: should be templateUrl, also take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609162/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-in-angular-resource. Hope it helps

Comment: Jax, as far as I know, TemplateUrl is used when we point to a file like "template/file.html", in this case I am using a HTML peace of code...

Comment: Right you are! my bad.

Comment: Try taking out the {{}} from <icone-timeline> tag. I tried taking it out and I didn't get that error

Comment: Jacky, I tried to take out but I got the same error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a long run I found the solution, the problem was:

```
replace:true,
```

After I removed this part the problem was solved.