# AngularJS Nondescript Error at "return logFn.apply(console, args);"

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS v`1.5.0`.  I'm on Chrome Version `55.0.2883.95`.  The error I'm seeing shows similar failure behavior to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609162/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-in-angular-resource) SO post, although the error description for my situation just states `Object`.

I've [created a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XFKeWa7lQzSSlCAKY9qp?p=preview) to demonstrate the error.  Open the developer console at the plunker to see the resulting error.

Given the following service,

```
this.test = function() {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        var errorObject = {
            httpStatusCode: 503,
            error: {
                code: 5030,
                message: 'Oh no! Something went wrong, please try again'
            }
        };
        reject(errorObject);

    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        return response;
    }).catch(function errorCallback(response) {
        throw response;
    });
};
```

AngularJS code generates the following error:

`angular.js:13550 Object {httpStatusCode: 503, error: Object}`

The AngularJS code in play is:

```
function consoleLog(type) {
  var console = $window.console || {},
      logFn = console[type] || console.log || noop,
      hasApply = false;

  // Note: reading logFn.apply throws an error in IE11 in IE8 document mode.
  // The reason behind this is that console.log has type "object" in IE8...
  try {
    hasApply = !!logFn.apply;
  } catch (e) {}

  if (hasApply) {
    return function() {
      var args = [];
      forEach(arguments, function(arg) {
        args.push(formatError(arg));
      });
      return logFn.apply(console, args); // Error thrown on this line
    };
  }

  // we are IE which either doesn't have window.console => this is noop and we do nothing,
  // or we are IE where console.log doesn't have apply so we log at least first 2 args
  return function(arg1, arg2) {
    logFn(arg1, arg2 == null ? '' : arg2);
  };
```

[image: Error Image]

Here's how I call the service:

```
var test = function() {
    userService.test()
        .then(function successCallback(responseObject) {
            console.log('Beginning of then');
        })
        .catch(function errorCallback(errorResponseObject) {
            console.log('Beginning of catch');
        });
}
```

The error seems to be caused by the fact that I am handling the promise rejection, and then re-throwing it.  If I don't catch and rethrow, I don't get the error.  Why do I receive the error when catching and re-throwing?

---

**Update**: It appears that using the $q service to reject the caught promise rejection avoids the AngularJS error I was seeing.  I'll use that approach for now, but would still be interested to know why throwing out of the promise catch generates the error.

Example code without the error:

```
this.test = function() {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        var errorObject = {
            httpStatusCode: 503,
            error: {
                code: 5030,
                message: 'Oh no! Something went wrong, please try again'
            }
        };
        reject(errorObject);

    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        return response;
    }).catch(function errorCallback(response) {
        return $q.reject(response);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found what I believe to be the answer to my question.  Buried in [this discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13990) on the AngularJS Github issues section, @gkalpak notes the following:

> The only difference between them is that return $q.reject(anything) will just pass anything down the chain, while throw anything will additionally pass anything to the $exceptionHandler. Other than that, both methods work the same.

So, the issue as far as I understand it, is that the `$exceptionHandler` prints the  exception to the console.  Using `$q.reject` as I stated in my update and again below does avoid this behavior and is my recommended solution to avoiding the console error.

```
this.test = function() {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        var errorObject = {
            httpStatusCode: 503,
            error: {
                code: 5030,
                message: 'Oh no! Something went wrong, please try again'
            }
        };
        reject(errorObject);

    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        return response;
    }).catch(function errorCallback(response) {
        return $q.reject(response);
    });
};
```

---

**Update** - Based on @Sanders-Eias answer below, it is bad practice to throw exceptions out of async functions in general.  That statement further bolsters the $q.reject approach.

Answer (score 0):

This question has nothing to do with AngularJS and much more on how promises work (including AngularJS's $q). 
Throwing in a `.catch` is bound to have issues. Axel has an [excellent explanation](http://www.2ality.com/2016/03/promise-rejections-vs-exceptions.html)

if you want a quick and dirty method to get an exception to the console(or other logging mechanisms) you can use this trick:

`.catch((err) => setTimeout(() => throw err));`

Or its es5 variant:

`.catch(function (err) { setTimeout(function () {throw err},0)})`

This will keep the error as is, and get it out of the promise chain, without changing it.
However, I think it's better to incorporate the way that Axel explains in his article.